# Creating model field to store multiple text inputs in django

Tags: python, html, django

i created a form on html with a dynamically increasing text field. how do i store all the inputs from the text fields under the single 'collaborators' attribute in my django models.py?

this is my html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var i=1;
            $('#addCollab').click(function(){
                i++;
                $('#dynamicField').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="collab" id="collab'+i+'"></td><td><button type="button" name="removeCollab" id="'+i+'" class="removeCollab">x</button></td></tr>')
            });
            $(document).on('click', '.removeCollab', function(){  
                var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
                $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="formGrp">
        <form>
            <div class="collaborators">
                <table id="dynamicField">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for="collabID">Collaborator Names: </label>
                            <input type="text" name="collab" id="collab1">
                        </td>
                        <td><button type="button" name="addCollab" id="addCollab">Add Collaborator</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

python code:

```py
class projectDetails(models.Model):
    project_id=models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    #collaborators=
    date_created=models.DateTimeField(auto_add_now=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store it as json data in django model. Here is the code that will handle

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class projectDetails(models.Model):
    project_id=models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    collaborators= JSONField()
    date_created=models.DateTimeField(auto_add_now=True)
```

this work with django>1.9 and postgres